# Add class to parent element from directive

Tags: angularjs, twig

I'm trying to add a `has-error` class to a div (input's parent), but I can't access the input's `name` in the twig because the `name` comes from php and it's not available there, so I can't use the `ng-class` attribute.

I have a directive connected to that input and it can detect if `ngModelCtrl.$invalid` is true or false and I'm trying to add the class from that.

Input twig:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="integerInputValue" integer-input 
       {{ block('widget_attributes') }}
       {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %} />
```

Directive:

```
(...)
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        // Workaround so that we don't lose the value.
        scope.integerInputValue = attrs.value;

        attrs.$set('ngPattern', '/^-?[0-9]+$/');

        function fromUser (text) {
          if (ngModelCtrl.$invalid) {
            angular.element(element).parent().addClass('has-error');
          } else if (ngModelCtrl.$valid) {
            angular.element(element).parent().removeClass('has-error');
          }
(...)
```

What I tried was to detect if `ngModelCtrl.$invalid` is true or false inside the `fromUser` function that detects every char inputed and from there, add or remove the class.
I also have the `ng-pattern` that only allows [0-9] and a "-" as first char.

This kinda works because the class is added and removed, but, for example:

`50-` doesn't get the class, `50--` does and when deleting,`50` still has the class and `5` doesn't.

I'm guessing there is be a better way of adding a class to the parent.

Comment: What is the reason that the twig can't actually write the HTML name attribute on the element?  Could you not write a twig extension or something to pull the correct `name` from your php?

Comment: If I inspect the input, it has a name `name="wizard_page_type[blocks][0][answers][0][value]"`, I just can't use it on the `ng-class`

Comment: Is it possible to assign static (or at least more predictable) name at the twig level?  What is wrong with just adding a `name` attribute in your twig?

Comment: Answering the first question I'd say no, I don't think it would be. If I add a `name` myself, it replaces the existing one and the input stops accepting any value as valid

Comment: The `$attrs.$set` method does not interpret AngularJS directives, it only normalizes and sets attributes. It will not link the `ng-pattern` directive.

Answer (score 1):

> If I inspect the input, it has a name `name="wizard_page_type[blocks][0][answers][0][value]"`

To use a name like that in `ng-class`, use a bracket property accessor:

```
<form name='form1'>
    <input name="wizard_page_type[blocks][0][value]"
           ng-model="kk" required >
</form>

<div ng-class="{'has-error': form1['wizard_page_type[blocks][0][value]'].$invalid}">
</div>
```

The best way for the `ngModelController` to work with forms is to have sensible names for inputs. The `ngModelController` uses that name when registering with the `ngFormController`.

The role of forms in client-side AngularJS applications is different than in classical roundtrip apps, it is desirable for the browser not to translate the form submission into a full page reload that sends the data to the server. Instead AngularJS apps POST JSON data with XHRs and receive responses as JSON data.